# Move the title on product pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to move the title of my products on top (on top of the image) but i'm not sure how to do it... I want the title to be uptop on the product page not the archive page.
I've spent a long time researching about how to do it but nothing seems to work...

Is there a hook to move it ? Maybe change the layout on the product_page.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better understanding the product template see the default content-single-product.php - https://gist.github.com/dompascal/7825580 and use this visual map - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

In your functions.php file in your active theme add the following:
**Solution #1**

```
//First remove default title
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
//Second add your title in thumbnail section - Keep in mind that title will be below the image bcs of the way this hook works
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
```

**Solution #2**
Another way is to place title above all (depends on your design)

```
//First remove default title
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
//Second add title
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
```

**Solution #3**
Override woocommerce templates in your theme. There is alot of examples but this is a good starting point - https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
This solution will provide the best output of your template BUT will require more maintance in future.

**If you use theme that override those templates or hooks then you need to work with the theme hooks. But this is specific per theme.**

Answer (score 0):

First solution didnt worked but it might be related to my theme.

Second solution worked like a charm even tho i changed the hook :)

To answer my question : **How to move the title on top of the product :**

```
//First remove default title
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
//Second add title
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
```